# Kotlin - Is kotlin contain Object class like base class in java?

Tags: kotlin

In my code i defined below variable,

```
var obj_str: Object = "NEW" as Object
```

which gives warning `This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.Any instead`

So, i need to know **Any** is similar to **Object** in kotlin or any thing else?

Also need to know for wait method like wait(), notify() etc are available in Object class but not in Any, so perform that operation in kotlin?

Comment: Have you tried that "prior research" thing? Like putting "kotlin any" into any search engine?!

Comment: @GhostCat i had tried that for 20 mins few years back, but surpringly couldn't find an answer. So updated this question even one can feel dumb

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) is the root of the Kotlin class hierarchy exactly like [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the root of the Java class hierarchy.

In other words, every non-nullable type is a subtype of `Any` in Kotlin, and all types are subtypes of `Any?`.

When using Kotlin on the JVM, it's actually just [mapped](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) to `Object` under the hood, so they are the exact same thing.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't actually have non-nullable _classes_; it has non-nullable _types_. A [`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/index.html) has an [isMarkedNullable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/is-marked-nullable.html) property while [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/) doesn't. i.e. Every class is a subclass of `Any` in Kotlin, and all types are subtypes of `Any?`.

Comment: if any class is same as Object class, then why any class does not have all the methods as object class, where are wait, notify and other methods ?

Comment: @sanjaykm I suppose they are explicitly hidden.

Comment: The comment here about types was quite correct. I don't know why I didn't fix my answer at the time, but I did now! Thank you, @mfulton26.

As for why some things aren't visible on `Any`, indeed, [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) often hide some of the members of the type that they map to.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be written like this.

`var obj_str: Any = "NEW" //You don't need to cast it`
or

`var obj_str: Any? = "NEW" //If obj_str could be null`